# How to share variable among more than 2 operation

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have a question about blender's python script.
I would like to share variables among more than two operations, however I don't know how to.

If I use global variable, it's easy to solve this problem.

```
selected_faces = []
class SelectFace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Select Face"
    def execute(self, context):
        global selected_faces
        selected_faces = ...   # get selected faces.
        .....
class OperationAboutSelectedFaces(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operation About selected Face"
    def execute(self, context):
        global selected_faces
        # some operation to "selected_faces"
```

However, I want to avoid using global variable.
So, I would like to rewrite this code as follows...

```
class SelectFace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Select Face"
    def execute(self, context):
        selected_faces = ... # get selected faces.
        .....
class OperationAboutSelectedFaces(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operation About selected Face"
    def execute(self, context):
        # some operation to "selected_faces"
```

Assuming operation sequence are as follows.

1. "Select Face"
2. "Operation About selected faces"

Thanks!

Comment: see [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13864/5113), [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18118/5113) and [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6032/5113)

Comment: I tried this [one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13864/how-can-a-parameter-be-passed-from-one-operator-to-another). However this solution makes error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'operator' because class is derived from bpy.types.Operator. Is there any solutions passed variables between bpy.types.Operator?

Comment: Both of your classes are global, you can store arbitrary data on them if you really have to: `SelectFace.your_global = 123`

Comment: Can't you pass your selected faces into the constructor of your derived class?  Create a constructor (`__init__`) and pass your `selected_faces` into it.  It would be something like this (check syntax):  `def  __init__(self, selectedFaces):`

Comment: @nutti is this your answer it is just a comment ?

Comment: Yes it's a comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know that answer must be a complete solution. I post the problem here again.
I add below code in `__init__` constructor.
`self.selected_faces = SelectFace.selected_faces`
However self.selected_faces is NoneType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve this problem.

Solution is shown below.

- Create user defined class which has properties you want.
- Register class to bpy.types.Scene.XXXXX when add-on is started
- Get data from bpy.context.scene.XXXXX
- Unregister class to bpy.types.Scene.XXXXX when add-on is stopped

```py
class SelectFaceProp():
    selected_faces = None

class SelectFace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Select Face"
    def execute(self, context):
        props = bpy.context.scene.sf_props
        props.selected_faces = ... # get selected faces.
        .....
class OperationAboutSelectedFaces(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operation About selected Face"
    def execute(self, context):
        props = bpy.context.scene.sf_props
        # some operation to "props.selected_faces"

def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.sf_props = SelectFaceProp()

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.sf_props
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I solved this problem using static variable.

```python
class SelectFace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Select Face"
    selected_faces = None
    def __init__(self):
        SelectFace.selected_faces = None
    def execute(self, context):
        SelectFace.selected_faces = ... # get selected faces.
        .....
class OperationAboutSelectedFaces(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operation About selected Face"
    def __init__(self):
        selected_faces = SelectFace.selected_faces
    def execute(self, context):
        # some operation to "selected_faces"
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use global or static variables, the proper concept to use is Blender's **context**. Note that this is not a Python mechanism, but something provided by Blender.

The context keeps track of the state of Blender in things such as 'what is the selected scene? what is the active object? what is the current selection?'. This information can then be used by all of Blender's operators, not just your own. Operators, in turn, also affect the context, by for example, modifying the current selection.
If you bypass the context, there will be some inconsistencies, such as operators working on your previous selection, because you never changed it in the context.

How to set that a given face is selected:

```
face.selected = True
```

Hot to get all selected faces in a mesh:

```
selected_faces = [face for face in mesh.faces if face.select]
```

The mesh can be obtained from the *context* that is passed as an argument to the operator's `execute`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to use global and static variable too. However, there is no way to pass variable between bpy.types.Operators. However I tried to store bpy.types.Scene.XXX, It doesn't work...

Comment: You can store new properties in anything that is an ID. Scene should indeed work, as would an operator, but it really needs to be a new Blender property, not just a python variable. See [bpy.props](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.props.html)

Comment: OK. By the way, is there any way to share PointerProperty? I can share IntProperty/FloatProperty, but I can't share PointerProperty.